# Matlab-Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab, subscript, bsxfun, matrix-indexing

Where did I go wrong? 
the problem is in: **R = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,XX,(XX)').^2+bsxfun(@minus,YY,(YY)').^2);**

```
EO = 8.8541e-12; %eps0
A2 = 1.0e-2; %2a
N = 100; %num of subareas in a plate
M = sqrt(N); %num of subareas in one axis
DX = A2/M; % 2b
DY = DX; %2b
DL = DX; %2b

%  SECOND, CALCULATE THE ELEMENS OF THE COEFFICIENT MATRIX A
% Write all the subareas centers coordinates to X and Y 
%  SECOND, CALCULATE THE ELEMENS OF THE COEFFICIENT MATRIX A
% Write all the subareas centers coordinates to X and Y 
x = linspace(DL*0.5,DL*(M-0.5),M);
y = x;
[XX,YY]=meshgrid(x,y);
%%L = NaN(N,N);
**R = sqrt(bsxfun(@minus,XX,(XX)').^2+bsxfun(@minus,YY,(YY)').^2);**
idx_diagL = find(eye(N)~=0);
idx_not_diagL = find(eye(N)==0);
L(idx_not_diagL) = DL^2./(4.*pi*EO*R(mod(idx_not_diagL,10),floor(idx_not_diagL/N)));
L(idx_diagL)  = DL*0.8814/(pi*EO); %ln(1+sqrt(2)= 0.8814
```

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is *not* where you say it is, but in the following line:

```
L(idx_not_diagL) = DL^2./(4.*pi*EO*R(mod(idx_not_diagL,10),floor(idx_not_diagL/N)));
```

In short, your problem is that you specify zero indices for matrix `R`, but in MATLAB zero indices are illegal (they start from 1, not 0!).

Now, where do you get zero indices? You index into `R(..., ...)` by using the following row and column subscripts:

```
mod(idx_not_diagL, 10)
```

and

```
floor(idx_not_diagL / N))
```

which both get zero values occasionally.

As a fix, I recommend using the following for the row indices:

```
mod(idx_not_diagL, 10) + 1
```

As for the column indices, there is another problem. The `floor(...)` expression ranges from 0 to 99. Once you fix it (I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve), it will work.

Comment: Thanks but I think what I've tried to do is like impossible mission... I tried to make R the NXN Distance Matrix but failed.... Ofcourse what I did here is R(10,10) instead and tried to figure out the right indices while accessing R ,pretty hardcore...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you've just said.